# auto-name keyword arguments after variable names

Tags: python

I often find myself doing this:

```
myvariable = 'whatever'
another = 'something else'

print '{myvariable} {another}'.format(
    myvariable=myvariable,
    another=another
)
```

Is there a way not to have to name the keyword arguments in this repetitive manner? I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
format_vars = [myvariable, another]

print '{myvariable} {another}'.format(format_vars)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use locals():

```
print '{myvariable} {another}'.format(**locals())
```

It's also possible (in Cpython at least) to pick format variables automatically from the scope, for example:

```
def f(s, *args, **kwargs):
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    d = {}
    d.update(frame.f_globals)
    d.update(frame.f_locals)    
    d.update(kwargs)
    return Formatter().vformat(s, args, d)
```

Usage:

```
myvariable = 'whatever'
another = 'something else'

print f('{myvariable} {another}')
```

See [Is a string formatter that pulls variables from its calling scope bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13312240/989121) for more details about this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
>>> format_vars = {"myvariable": "whatever",
...                "another": "something else"}
>>> print('{myvariable} {another}'.format(**format_vars))
whatever something else
```