# Getting a hold of locals() from surrounding frame

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to replace my `Template(s).substitute("$a,$b", locals())` with something short like

```
sub("$a,$b")
```

However, I don't have access to locals of surrounding scope inside `sub()`, any idea how to get them?
One possible workaround I found is to throw an exception, catch it, and step along the frames to find the previous frame, but perhaps there's an easier way?

```
import traceback, sys, code
try:
  2/0
except Exception as e:
  type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
  traceback.print_exc()
  last_frame = lambda tb=tb: last_frame(tb.tb_next) if tb.tb_next else tb
  frame = last_frame().tb_frame
  ns = dict(frame.f_globals)
```

Comment: why not just pass locals()?

Comment: related: [Is a string formatter that pulls variables from its calling scope bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13312240/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`sys._current_frames()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys._current_frames) instead of raising exception.

Possible alternatives: [`sys._getframe()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe), [`inspect.currentframe()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe), [`inspect.stack()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack)

I cant think of better solution, than analysing frames.

Comment: current_frames() gives me dictionary with 1 frame -- the current one. But I need locals from the previous frame

Comment: Yes, _current_frames maps thread to frames, rest of them (functions from post) return frame of specified depth in stack. If you have single frame, you can follow it's f_back attribute to obtain calling frame for the one that you hold. I linked docs for those functions, so you can read it and figure out how to navigate in stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it directly via[`sys._getframe()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=_getframe#sys._getframe), although it's only guaranteed to work with CPython.

```
from string import Template
import sys

def sub(template):
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_locals  # caller's locals
    return Template(template).substitute(namespace)

a, b = 1, 42
print sub("$a,$b")  # -> 1,42
```