# Python's self argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        print "New Point object", self, "constructed"

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"

    def __del__(self):
        print "Destructor"

pt1 = Point()
```

Output:

```
New Point object (0,0) constructed
```

Method functions receive a special first argument, called `self` by very strong convention, which is the instance object that is the implied subject of the method call, and gives access to instance attributes.

So why is `self` in **init**() printing `(0, 0)` instead of `pt1`? Isn't `pt1` the instance object?

Comment: That's because you've explicitly defined how the thing is to be printed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/592849/1443496 if you want this functionality.

Comment: `pt1` is simply the name to which the object is assigned, it has **no connection** to the object's identity or display (indeed, the object doesn't "know" that's what you think its name is). See e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitly telling the `Point` object to display itself as `(x,y)` when you define the `__str__` method. In order for the print to work it must convert itself to a string, and it does that by calling the `__str__` method.

Notice what happens when you remove the `__str__` method:

```
New Point object <__main__.Point instance at 0x1005da488> constructed
```

In this case, python must still convert the object to a string in order to print it, but since there is no explicit definition of `__str__` it uses it's own default implementation.

In either case, the object itself doesn't know it was assigned to `pt1` so it has no way of printing that information. In fact, the same object could be assigned to multiple variables, or none at all (ie: it could be a member of a list).

Here's the link to the python 2.7 documentation on `__str__`:

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Answer (score 0):

It is printing `(0,0)` because that is how the `__str__` method is defined.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "(" + str(self.x) + "," + str(self.y) + ")"
```

It prints `self.x` and `self.y` along with some formatting.

And since you instatiated the Point as

```
pt1 = Point()
```

It will use the default arguments `0` and `0` from the `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
```

So it is working exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've explicitly defined how the thing is to be printed.  See [How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592746/1443496) if you want the functionality you describe.

---

If your interested in introspection, explore everything in `dir(pt1)`.