# Understanding gc.get_referrers

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm trying to track a memory leak in Python (2.7).
I've found gc.get_referrers, but don't understand the output.  After deleting `dying_node` (which should get rid of all references except for a list that I've created as part of my hunting), I have in my code:

```
gc.collect()
print "done dying: ", getrefcount(dying_node) #note, includes the reference from getrefcount
referrers = gc.get_referrers(dying_node)
print "referrers: "
for referrer in referrers:
    print referrer
```

which yields the output:

```
> done dying:   4
> referrers: 
> [<__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53cb0>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53b90>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53b00>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53d40>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53ab8>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53bd8>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53a70>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53c20>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53c68>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53b48>]
> [<__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53c20>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53ab8>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53c68>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53a70>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53cb0>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53b00>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53d40>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53b90>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53b48>, <__main__.Node instance at 0x104e53bd8>]
> <frame object at 0x104516300>
```

I think this means I have two lists of `Node`s which refer to this node and a frame object.  I assume the frame object is the name `dying_node` that I'm looking at.  One of the lists would be a list I've created to help me in my hunting.  But is there a way to figure out what the other list would be?

Comment: Use `weakref.WeakSet` etc. for your hunting lists, so they don't count as referrers.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so an answer is

```
def namestr(obj, namespace):
    return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj]
```

Example:

```
gc.collect() #make sure all garbage cleared before collecting referrers.
referrers = gc.get_referrers(object_of_interest)
for referrer in referrers:
    print namestr(referrer, globals())
```

or if it's local:

```
    print namestr(referrer, locals())
```

This will print something like `['referrer', 'name_Im_interested_in']`.  The `'referrer'` is because of the fact I've just named it that.  The other thing in the list is what I'm trying to find.

I borrowed this from [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python).  If anyone has a better answer, please post it and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: "or if it's local" - if what is local? How can you tell?

Comment: if `objectofinterest` is local (if I recall correctly).  I don't know offhand how one tells in advance, but I presume it would be clear based on the code.  Long time since I've thought of this, and obviously, I wasn't an expert at the time otherwise I wouldn't have been asking the question.