# Detecting memory leaks & dumping statistics in python

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I am looking for python memory debugging techniques?
Basically I am looking at tools available for python and see what data we can look at when a python process is taking lot of memory?
I am aiming to isolate such memory eating process and **dump statistics**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `guppy`

```
from guppy import hpy
import networkx as nx

h = hpy()
L=[1,2,3]

h.heap()



> Partition of a set of 89849 objects. Total size = 12530016 bytes.
>  Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
>     0  40337  45  3638400  29   3638400  29 str
>     1  21681  24  1874216  15   5512616  44 tuple
>     2   1435   2  1262344  10   6774960  54 dict (no owner)
```

This will go a long way towards telling you where lots of memory is being used.

Python clears memory when an object is no longer accessible - nothing in the program points to it.  Sometimes you might be wondering what on earth is still pointing to a particular object.  For that you might look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403750/understanding-gc-get-referrers) which tells you how about how to find out what things are still referring to an object.