# Python, find variable/key based on maximum value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have several values, like this:

```
value_a = 5
value_b = 10
value_c = 20
```

I want to find the largest value and print the NAME of the value.
normally I would use

```
val = [value_a, value_b, value_c]
print max (val)
```

but this only gives me the value and not the name.

Comment: You are mixing data and code, use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python

Comment: not short but you can use `if...elif`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of defining variable, you need to create a `dict` to map the name with the value. Then you need to call [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as `key` to it. For example:

```
my_dict = {
   'value_1': 10,
   'value_2': 30,
   'value_3': 20
}

from operator import itemgetter

var_text, value = max(my_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1))   
# Value of:
# `var_text`: "value_2"
# `value`: 30
```

Here, `max()` will return the tuple with maximum value in the `dict`.

If you do not care about the maximum value, and you just want the `key` holding it, you may do:

```
>>> max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
'value_2'
```

**Explanation:**

`my_dict.items()` will return list of tuple in the format `[(key, value), ..]`. In the example I gave, it will hold:

```
[('value_1', 10), ('value_3', 20), ('value_2', 30)]
```

`key=itemgetter(1)` in the satement will tell `max()` to perform the max operation on the index `1` of each tuple in the list.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. :)

```
In [1]: the_dict = {'value_a':5, 'value_b':10, 'value_c':20}

In [2]: max(the_dict, key=the_dict.get)
```

The output:

```
Out[2]: 'value_c'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dictionary or named tuple. Example using dictionary is below

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep 14 2016, 12:36:27) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> vdict={'value_a':5,'value_b':10,'value_c':20}
>>> max(vdict, key=vdict.get)
'value_c'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary for the values and then simply call this function in the print statement.

```
values = {
   'value_1': 10,
   'value_2': 30,
   'value_3': 20
}

print (max(values, key=lambda i: values[i]))
```

Output:

```
value_2
```