# How to get the name of a variable in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

I want to run a function that will create a file with the name of a variable and write in it the content of that variable.

```
list_A = 'one two three'.split()

def write_list(list_to_write): 
    flux = open('%s.list' %list_to_write, 'w')
    flux.write('\n'.join(list_to_write))
    flux.close()

write_list (list_A)
```

This creates a file called `['one', 'two', 'three'].list`

I would like it to create a file called `liste_A.list` instead.

PS: I found many similar posts, but none that seemed to address my issue.

Comment: In general objects do not have `names`.  You should just pass the name (label) and the list to `write_list`

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean by "You should just pass the name (label) and the list to write_list"

Comment: @JonathP there is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/592849/119861) which does exactly what you want

Comment: but in general you don't want to do this, as it's bad practice, as you see by the kind of code you need to achieve it

Comment: Names are *labels*, not *properties*. See e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in other languages like tcl for example, but not in Python.

If you really need to manage lists and their names, you can use a dictionary for this, for example:

```
lists = {}
lists['list_A'] = 'one two three'.split()

...

write_list('list_A')
```

And then `write_list` would use `lists[list_to_write]` to access the list

Comment: it [is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/592849/119861) in python