# How to show variable order in python lists?

Tags: python

How would you go about displaying the order of the variables in python after using `sort()`. For an example:

```
A=3
B=1
C=2
D=[A,B,C]
```

`D.sort()` would be `[1,2,3]`, but I want to see `[B,C,A]` somehow

Comment: [Taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592816/9070959). If you want to do this you should be using a dictionary.

Comment: @emsimpson92 can't sort a dictionary.  You *can* sort dictionary items however

Comment: @user3483203 You can actually, [you just have to do it a bit differently](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/)

Comment: `for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=whatever):` works just fine. Or `od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=whatever)`. For that matter, in Python 3.7+, dictionaries are guaranteed to retain insertion order, so you can just do `dd = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=whatever)`.

Comment: @emsimpson92 that's not sorting a dictionary, that's getting a sorted view of its items.  Nothing in that article changes anything about the dictionary

Comment: OP isn't trying to sort a dictionary though, they are trying to sort a list of letters.

Comment: @abarnert is it correct to say that there isn't an in-place sort for dictionaries in Python? Or will that be possible in 3.7?

Comment: @user3483203 There is no in-place sort method, and there probably never will be (especially since the idea of adding `move_to_end` and friends from `OrderedDict` was rejected).

Comment: @stybl, the letters are only references, it is actually sorting a list of integers

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with independent variables just floating around would be extremely difficult. Why not use a dictionary instead?

```
myDict = {"A":3, "B":1, "C":2}
D = ["A", "B", "C"]
D.sort(key=lambda l:myDict[l])
```

Here we have each letter and its corresponding number in a dictionary. We have a list of letters out of order, which we call `sort()` on. Instead of using the default comparisons however, we provide our own sorting function in the form of an inline lambda function, which gets the number from the dictionary that matches each letter.

In case you aren't familiar with the lambda syntax, it is the same as doing this but more compact:

```
def customSort(l):
    return myDict[l]

D.sort(key=customSort)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.OrderedDict`, you can feed a list of key-value pairs sorted by value.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}

res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))

# get keys ordered by value
print(res.keys())
odict_keys(['B', 'C', 'A'])

# get ordered values
print(res.values())
odict_values([1, 2, 3])
```