# an easier way of comparing four lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made four lists that all have some values and I want to say to computer to print the name of that list which has the greatest length.

I tried this code

```
list1=[values,values,values]
list2=[values,values,values]
list3=[values,values,values]
list4=[values,values,values]
if len(list1)>len(list2) and len(list1)>len(list3) and len(list1)>len(list4):
    print(True)
```

but it takes all my time and I need to compare list2 to others and list 3 and list4 so is there a way that I just do like this:

```
if len(list1)>(len(list2) and len(list3) and len(list4)):
    print(True)
```

or this
    print(that list which has the greatest length)

Comment: max(len(list1),len(list2),len(list3),len(list4))

Comment: `print(max([list1, list2, list3, list4], key=len))`

Answer (score 4):

What about using max:

```
lists = (list1, list2, list3, list4)
print(max(lists, key=len))
```

Comment: not sure it should be more efficient to use iter rather than a tuple

Comment: @njzk2 Oh, you are probably right, at least in this case (I just tend to use iterators if I do not need lists)

Comment: I've got an error when I tried to use your second answer: `TypeError: iter expected at most 2 arguments, got 4`

Comment: @joumaico thanks for the  notice, I removed the second solution completely

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the optimal solution but you can make a function like such:

```
def check(main,*lists):
    for l in lists:
        if len(l) > len(main):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that it's really complicated to print variable names in python (Some explanations for example in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python).

The easiest way would be to rewrite the first assignments to use a dictionary:

```py
lists = {
  "list1": [ values ... ],
  "list2": [ values ... ],
  "list3": [ values ... ],
  "list4": [ values ... ]
}
```

(after that, instead of referring to list1, you have to refer to `lists["list1"]` instead)

Then you could get the longest list by this method for example:

```py
print(max(lists, key=len))
```