# How to print a dictionary's name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
daisy = {
    'type' : 'dog',
    'owner' : 'miranda',
    }

bella = {
    'type' : 'cat',
    'owner' : 'luke',
    }

charlie = {
    'type' : 'lizard',
    'owner' : 'mike',
}

pets = [daisy, bella, ruby]
```

How to print out only the names of the dictionaries i.e. daisy, bella, charlie from a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python)

Comment: You should probably create a `pets` dictionary with the pet names as keys

Comment: Use a nested dictionary instead of individual variables. Then you just do `your_dict.keys()`.

Comment: Printing variable names at runtime is (almost) never what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an xy problem. You should never need to print the names of variables. The reason is that the data structures often get passed around in ways that the names of the variable get lost. This is what happens when you do:

```
pets = [daisy, bella, ruby]
```

Here `pets` is just a list of dictionaries...they are no longer named.

If the name is significant, then it should be part of the data. For example:

```
daisy = {
    'name': 'Daisy',
    'type': 'dog',
    'owner': 'miranda',
    }

bella = {
    'name': 'Bella',
    'type': 'cat',
    'owner': 'luke',
    }

charlie = {
    'name': 'Charlie',
    'type': 'lizard',
    'owner': 'mike',
}

pets = [daisy, bella, charlie]

for pet in pets:
    print(pet['name'])
```

Prints:

```
Daisy
Bella
Charlie
```

In fact, you can get rid of the named variable altogether now:

```
pets = [
    {
        'name': 'Daisy',
        'type': 'dog',
        'owner': 'miranda',
    },
    {
        'name': 'Bella',
        'type': 'cat',
        'owner': 'luke',
    },
    {
        'name': 'Charlie',
        'type': 'lizard',
        'owner': 'mike',
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
daisy = {
    'type' : 'dog',
    'owner' : 'miranda',
    }

bella = {
    'type' : 'cat',
    'owner' : 'luke',
    }

ruby = {
    'type' : 'lizard',
    'owner' : 'mike',
}

pets = [daisy, bella, ruby]

for i, e in list(globals().items()):
    if e in pets:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
daisy = {
    'name': 'Daisy',
    'type': 'dog',
    'owner': 'miranda',
    }

bella = {
    'name': 'Bella',
    'type': 'cat',
    'owner': 'luke',
    }

charlie = {
    'name': 'Charlie',
    'type': 'lizard',
    'owner': 'mike',
}

pets = [daisy, bella, charlie]

for i in pets:
    name = i["name"]
    print(name)
```