# Get user input and loop through a lot of variables in order to match that input to one of the variables

Tags: python

I have created an ASCII map of an island in a school project. There are over 140 variables which are used to print the names of the places in the island.

I don't just put the names in text because I am trying to find a way to get user input and match that input to a variable. Then assign a ASCII color code along with its original string to that variable in order to appear a different color than the others when the map is printed.

Let's say:

```
map = x + """ ------------- """ + y 
x = "x"
y = "y"
red = "\033[31m" #color code

place = input("Where do you want to go?: ")
```

If the user enters "x" then the "x" should appear in red color.

I used `"""` instead of `"` because my actual map consists of way more lines and I wanted to point that out incase it makes a difference.

I know I could just use `if` and `elif` to achieve that. But that would result to a lot of lines of code since I am dealing with a lot more variables.

So I was wondering if there was a way to loop through those variables and find the correct one every time?

I think a dictionary is the way to go since that's what people suggested in my last post but I am not sure how to implement it in actual python code.

The teacher mentioned that we should not use index in order to skip the variable part and just put the color codes in the map itself before the correct words.

Comment: The answer is the same as it was before.  If you have a list of items, then you don't want to put them in individual variables.  Rather, you want to put them in some kind of data structure.  You even allude to this your self in mentioning a dictionary.  A dictionary is probably what you want, although it's still unclear given that your question still does not really describe what you want to do with a user's input once you've determined that they've entered a valid place name.

Comment: Once they've entered a valid place name, the goal is for the "red" color code to be assigned to the variable containing that place name. Since this ain't a real program scenario and is just an exercise there is the very annoying restriction for us to use these variables.. I am not really familiar with dictionaries.. To be honest I know almost nothing about them so my question might again not make sense for someone more experienced but I am not sure how to phrase it better than that.

Comment: So you have to have 140+ unique variables in your program, and when the user enters "x" in the above example, you want to perform `x = "\033[31m"`? It is an absolute requirement that you set that variable's value?  If this is the case, then I know of no good way to do this other than having 140+ `if` statements.  I don't know of any other way to set an individual variable.  This is why this is never done.  I find it surprising, and frankly wrong, for your instructor to insist on this behavior.  Or maybe I still don't get what you need to accomplish.

Comment: No you actually got it. Only thing x will not be equal only to "\033[31m", it will be x = "\033[31m" + x  . The reason behind the strange restrictions is to teach us how to achieve the same goal with different ways (even unorthodox ones).At least that's what he said :)..  It might even be one of those exercises where the instructor does not expect an actual answer and just gives the exercise to see what we'll come up with. I really do not know I've used all my brain power trying to avoid writing 140 different "if" statements x) (which seems too obvious to even be a solution btw)

Comment: If you want to be really clever and blow your instructor away, there may be a way to find a global variable and set its value given its name.   But that's Python hackery.  It's not something any of us do in normal course.  But if you think this is kind of a "trick question", then maybe that's what your instructor is looking for.  If it's a beginning Python class though, that wouldn't make much sense.  Nothing about what you say is being requested makes much sense.  I'll do some googling, but until I or someone else comes up with something better, you're talking 140+ `if` statements :(

Comment: I'm curious to hear if my answer nailed your problem given how much time you've put into presenting it not just once, but twice.  I'm also curious what your instructor will think of this solution, and if that's what they were looking to have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

READER BEWARE: The OP has had artificial constraints placed on them by their instructor.  The mechanism demonstrated here is not something I'd suggest be used in production code. There are better ways of getting similar functionality, namely using common Python data structures rather than individual global variables. The big downside of this method, in addition to it being a hack, is that even though setting the variable values can be done simply by an entered name, you would have to change the code to add new "places". In production code, your map and the individual places on it should be fed to the code as input data. Your code shouldn't have to change when your map or list of places changes.

Knowing just what you want, I took a look, and immediately found that there is indeed a way to set the value of a global variable given its name.  That mechanism is the `globals()` call.  This call returns a dictionary containing references to all the global variables.  The keys are the variable names, and the values are tied to the actual values of the variables.

Here is the most basic example of this given the code in the question:

```
x = "x"
y = "y"
red = "\033[31m"  # color code

place = input("Where do you want to go?: ")

g = globals()
g[place] = red + g[place]

print("x =", x)
print("y =", y)
```

Test run 1:

[image]

Test run 2:

[image]

Notice that the added color code makes the output red from the point where that variable's value is printed until the end of the input.

Here's a more complete example that uses both a color code and an "end color" code so that only the variable's printed value is colored red.   In this example, you can keep inputting 1 of w, x, y or z, and then just press Return by itself to exit:

```
w = "w"
x = "x"
y = "y"
z = "z"

red = "\033[31m"  # color code
end="\033[0m" # cancel color code

g = globals()

while True:
    print("w =", w)
    print("x =", x)
    print("y =", y)
    print("z =", z)

    map = x + """ ------------- """ + y
    print("map =", map)

    place = input("Where do you want to go?: ")
    if not place:
        break
    g[place] = red + g[place] + end
```

Test run:

[image]

Note here that each variable name that you enter leads to that variable's value being changed to display in red.  This occurs because the value of the actual global variable is being modified and then the value of that variable is printed directly.  This was the key bit of functionality you were asking for.

BEWARE: This mechanism is not something I'd suggest that you use in production code.  There are better ways to do these things, namely using dictionaries or lists.  A downside of this method is that even though setting the variable values can be done simply, you still have to change your code to add "places".  In production code, your map and the individual places on it should be fed to the code as input data.  Your code shouldn't have to change when your map or list of places changes.

I hope this gives you what you needed.  Happy programming!

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you put into this! I just tested your solution and it works flawlessly! I achieved almost the the same thing as you in the answer above but in a worse way x) I kind of get tired of always finding the silly or unorthodox ways of solving a problem rather than going with the simple and most efficient solution but I guess my lack of experience in coding is the reason behind that. Could you possibly reference some book or site that I could use to improve? School is good but I feel like a bit of outside practice could help too!

Comment: Please upvote and checkmark the answer.  Just keep being curious, do a ton of reading, and keep writing code.  There's no replacement for experience, as you already know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you may have tried using a for loop in the past using a list variable?

Fortunately **dictionaries** act pretty much the same as lists, only they don't use index:value referencing (i.e. list[index] = value). They use key:value pairing (dict[key] = value).

The syntax uses curly braces like so:
dictionary{"key1": value1, "key2": value2, ....}.

This gives you a quick and easy way to reference a value without having to loop through loads of items. Unfortunately, it sounds like you'll have to build the dictionary yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there were some things I had to figure out by myself but you set me to the right direction which saved me a lot of valuable time! Giving me the general idea of dictionaries and explaining what's the difference between them and lists helped more than you would think.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. So I use a dictionary as mentioned above. I locate the variable containing the string that matches the usr_input, I store its value in a different variable lets call it "random". I remove the matching variable from the dictionary and then I add to the dictionary a new variable with the same name but with the correct value. So code looks something like that:

```
var1 = "one"
var2 = "two"
red="\033[31m"

dict = {var1: "one", var2:"two"}
print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{var1: "one", var2:"two"}
```

And now we edit that dict:

```
place = input("Enter: ")
#this is just the usr_input. Its here only so no one asks what does the variable "place" contain.

for k,v in list(dict.items()):
    if v == place:
        random = red + v #random now has the correct value we want
        new_key = f'{k}' #this gets the name of the variable which matches the usr_input
        del dict[k] #deletes the matching variable
        dict[new_key] = random 
# adds a new variable with the same name as the matching one and the correct value 
# we got from random
print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{var1: "one", var2:"\033[31mtwo"}
```

And now comes the part which I don't really now if it satisfies the restrictions. I no longer use the variables as:

```
map = "------" + var1 + "-------"
```

I get the values from the dictionary:

```
map = "-----" + dict[var2] + "-----"
```

Which gives the correct output. So I am NOT going to abandon nor change this somehow. I will leave it like that and pray there is nothing wrong with it. Completely unorthodox way of doing things but I ended up learning some stuff about dictionaries which I knew nothing about. Only question I got (probably gonna ask in class about it) is:
I don't really understand what does the `list()` do? I only know that without it I get a runtime error.

Other than that, thank you all for the answers and for setting me to the right direction. I know my terminology is so wrong cause I talk about a lot of things I don't fully understand yet. (especially the parts where I say value,variable,key etc) I really think I've messed those up! Hope I wasn't too much of a pain in the back for ya :)