# access variables in list python

Tags: python, list, variables, user-input

I need to acess a variable in list for example

```
var1=[Orange,Banana]
var2=[Apple,Pear]
var3=[Banana,Pear]
var4=[Grapes,Orange]
var5=[Orange,Apple]

user_fruit = str(input("Whats ur favorite fruit?: "))
```

*user inputs Orange, Pear

How do I somehow print out var1, var2 var3, var5, (like print out all variable with the user's input within their lists'.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `locals`, although it is almost never a good idea. It is better to structure your data as a dict in the first place, e.g. `{"var1": ["Orange", "Banana"]}`.

```
var1=["Orange","Banana"]
var2=["Apple","Pear"]
var3=["Banana","Pear"]
var4=["Grapes","Orange"]
var5=["Orange","Apple"]

# dict of all locally defined variables that start with "var"
my_vars = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k.startswith("var")}
# {'var1': ['Orange', 'Banana'],
#  'var2': ['Apple', 'Pear'],
#  'var3': ['Banana', 'Pear'],
#  'var4': ['Grapes', 'Orange'],
#  'var5': ['Orange', 'Apple']}

# user_fruit = str(input("Whats ur favorite fruit?: "))
user_fruit = "Banana"

# print all varnames containing user_fruit
for k, v in my_vars.items():
  if user_fruit in v:
    print(k)
# prints var1 and var3

# for faster lookup, you can preprocess the data so that each fruit 
# encodes a list of vars containing it
from collections import defaultdict

fruit_to_var = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my_vars.items():
  for fruit in v:
    fruit_to_var[fruit].append(k)

# another lookup:
print(fruit_to_var["Banana"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just access to name of variables (for example Orange), you can define them as string in one list.
Then for searching a name in list, You can do this:

```
user_input = str(input("Whats ur favorite fruit?: "))
mylist = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple' ,'Pear']
print(mylist[mylist == user_input])
```

But if you want name of variable (and its value), this link can help you:

[How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question. Could you please be more specific?
What I have figured out, I tried to solve it. Here is the snippet.

```py
var1 = ["Orange", "Banana"]
var2 = ["Apple", "Pear"]
var3 = ["Banana", "Pear"]
var4 = ["Grapes", "Orange"]
var5 = ["Orange", "Apple"]

newlst = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]

user_fruit = input("Whats ur favorite fruit?: ")
user_fruit = user_fruit.split(
    ", ") if ", " in user_fruit else user_fruit.split(",")

for fruit in user_fruit:
    for flist in newlst:
        if fruit in flist:
            print(flist)
```

**EDIT:**

```py
var1 = ["Orange", "Banana"]
var2 = ["Apple", "Pear"]
var3 = ["Banana", "Pear"]
var4 = ["Grapes", "Orange"]
var5 = ["Orange", "Apple"]

newlst = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]

user_fruit = input("Whats ur favorite fruit?: ")
user_fruit = user_fruit.split(
    ", ") if ", " in user_fruit else user_fruit.split(",")

for fruit in user_fruit:
    fruit_pos = user_fruit.index(fruit)
    for flist in newlst:
        if flist[fruit_pos] == fruit:
            print(flist)
```

It prints your var1, var2, var3 and var5. In other words, prints out all variable with the user's input within their lists.

Comment: I think you got it, but just wondering how to print the variable as well ('varNum = ["fruit", "fruit"]) instead of just the list