# How can I separate list of items into numbers, upper & lower case lists and then make a dictionary off these three lists?

Tags: python-3.x

for ex.

```
lst = [2,'j','K','o',6,'x',5,'A',3.2]
```

I want 3 lists in the form

```
numbers = [2, 3.2, 5, 6],
uppercase = ['A', 'K'],
lowercase = ['j', 'o', 'x']
```

I wish to change them into a dictionary of the form

```
{'numbers': [2, 3.2, 5, 6],
 'uppercase': ['A', 'K'],
 'lowercase': ['j', 'o', 'x']
```

how can I achieve this? any help will be appreciated

Comment: isn't it as straightforward as `d = {'numbers': numbers, ... }` ?

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python?

Comment: i am not sure why this got downvoted.  seems to be a perfectly logical question (in fact quite interesting).

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to the problem:

```
lst = [2,'j','K','o',6,'x',5,'A',3.2]

# get the numbers
numbers = [x for x in lst if type(x)==int or type(x)==float ]

# get the strings
strings = [x for x in lst if type(x)==str]

# get the uppers
upper = [x for x in strings if x.isupper()==True]

# get the lowers
lower = [x for x in strings if x.islower()==True]

# now put into a dict
d = {
    'numbers':numbers,
    'upper':upper,
    'lower':lower
    }

# this is the answer as a dict
print(d)

# here there are deperately
print(numbers)
print(upper)
print(lower)
```

result:

```
{'numbers': [2, 6, 5, 3.2], 'upper': ['K', 'A'], 'lower': ['j', 'o', 'x']}
```

And the lists:

```
[2, 6, 5, 3.2]
['K', 'A']
['j', 'o', 'x']
```