# setting data frame name automatically (not hardcoding)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function used by at least 1000 dataframes and I want to know each time this function is called, which df has passed to this function,

```
def multi_purp_df(df):
    print(f'Name of df passed is: {df.name}')
    return
```

I know one way is to set `df.name = df_client` before calling the function but this means setting the name 1000 times in different places! Is there any way to do this inside the function automatically? For example, with `multi_purp_df(df_client)`, I like to print `df_client`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python)

Comment: Use a dictionary to hold the dataframes, the keys will be the labels