# How to read the alias used in import on Python?

Tags: python, reflection

Example:

```py
import awesome as custom_import_name
import woot as custom_second_name


print(custom_import_name.__name__) # awesome, i want custom_import_name
print(custom_second_name.__name__) # woot, i want custom_second_name
```

Is possible to read the alias created here? I want to get **something_good**, **something_bad** instead of the awesome, woot names.

I did not find anything related to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "read the alias"? "Read" in what way? Can you give a code example of what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I update the question hope it helps, thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python