# Searching for a specific members of a list in Python

Tags: python

I make a Python script that searches for the specific things in a list (e.g. animals or flower).

Let's suppose I have variables such as:

```py
dog = 1
cat = 1
rose = 0
violet = 0
```

And a list of those things

```py
List_of_things = [dog, cat, rose, violet]
```

How do I make it so the print function only displays those members of a list that have a value of 0 or 1 (only animals or flowers)?

Comment: Your list is simply `[1, 1, 0, 0]`. It doesn't know what the original variable names were.

Comment: Helpful resource for understanding [Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About variables, evaluation and list creations

The following Python statements:

```
dog = 1
cat = 1
rose = 0
violet = 0
```

Will create variables named **dog**, **cat**, **rose** and **violet** with the values:

- 1 for the variable **dog**
- 1 for the variable **cat**
- 0 for the variable **rose**
- 0 for the variable **violet**

The type of all of these values are going to be **integer** (or **int**)

The following python statement:

```
List_of_things = [dog, cat, rose, violet]
```

Will create a variable called **List_of_things** and assign it the value of the expression in the right side of the **=** operator.

To assign the value of the expression in the right side of the **=** operator, it first has the evaluate the expression. The expression is the following:

```
[dog, cat, rose, violet]
```

This expression means, because of the **[** and **]** symbols, that you want a **new list** to be created from the **values** provided. But in our case the values provided are variables, which means they must be evaluated (in the case of a variable, converted to the value they hold) before they are provided as an item for the list to be created.

Therefore, the expression to be evaluated is equivalent to:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0]
```

And the **list** to be created won't store the information about which variables were used to create the **list**.

The expression then will be evaluated to the **list object** created from the provided values.

#### Solution with dict

One possible way of achieving the desired effect would be to use a **dict** to associate each possible **string (value)** to be printed to an **integer**.

```
integer_associated_to_string = {
    "dog" : 1,
    "cat" : 1,
    "rose" : 0,
    "violet" : 0
}
```

Then you could iterate over the entries of the **dict** and test for a condition:

```
for item in integer_associated_to_string:
    if integer_associated_to_string[item] in [0,1]:
        print(item)
```

Note in this case **item** will iterate over the key values of the **dict** (the values to the left of the **:** during the dict creation), and **integer_associated_to_string[item]** will evaluate to the value on the right of the **:** during the dict creation.

#### Solution with list of tuple

One limitation of the **dict** approach would be that dict keys must be unique, in this case a list of tuples would allow for repetition of string values in the list.

For example, for a new category associated with integer 2 meaning colors:

```
list_of_tuple = [
("dog", 1),
("cat", 1),
("rose", 0),
("violet", 0),
("violet", 2)
]
```

**violet** could also be a color (category 2), and dict wouldn't allow for this association.

To iterate in this case:

```
for item in list_of_tuple:
    if item[1] in [1,2]:
        print(item[0])
```

Here item[1] means the integer category and item[0] means the string itself.

Comment: OMG delta de dirac thank you for your detailed answer. you made everything clear to me !
thank you for your time and effort that you have put in. YOU ARE AWESOME <3

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not a good idea to reference variable names in your desired output. It *can* be done, but [it gets ugly very quickly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592849/17200348)

Instead I would opt for a dictionary, where you can keep the animal names as strings and store their values alongside them. Afterwards, you can use `filter()` to filter the keys of this dictionary based on the values.

```py
animals = {
    'dog': 1,
    'cat': 1,
    'rose': 0,
    'violet': 0
}

desired_value = 1

for animal, value in animals.items():
    if value == desired_value:
        print(animal)

# OR

print(*(animal for animal, value in animals.items() if value == desired_value))
```

Output:

```py
dog
cat

# OR

dog cat
```

Comment: I think OP meant "either show elements that have a value of 1, or that have a value of 0". Also that last line would be _much_ simpler as a list comprehension or just a generator: `print(*(x for x in animals if animals[x] == 1))`

Comment: Good point. That solution is much simpler, I got lost in trying to show that the initial idea would be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you should use a dictionary like this if you want to print the name like dog, cat, ...:

```
# It is a dictionary. It is a like a list, but the indexes are customized.
dict_of_things = {
    'dog' : 1,
    'cat' : 1,
    'boat' : 2000,
    'rose' : 0,
    'violet' : 0,
    'car' : 12
}


# This list (dict_of_things.keys()) will done ['dog', 'cat', 'boat', 'rose', 'violet', 'car']

# The .keys() is to get all the keys (names like dog, cat, etc.) of a dictionary.

# And the value keys of the 'for' will take 'dog' in the first run, after 'car', etc.

for keys in list(dict_of_things.keys()):

    # First run of the for will be:
    #   if 'dog' value (1) is in the list [0, 1]
    if(dict_of_things[keys] in [0, 1]):

        # First run:
        #print('dog')
        print(keys)
```

Output:

```
dog
cat
rose
violet
```

Comment: thank you @meniev for your answer can you explain the second part of your code the .keys part to me

Comment: The .keys() is to take the name of the dictionnary like cat, dog, etc.

Comment: @user22309639 I putted mores details in the code, does this help you understand?