# Python type-hinting: Possible to derive kwarg type hint based off a string value?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is it possible to derive a type-hint for a named keyword-argument for a function based off a string value passed into another parameter of that function?

Example:

```
def magic_params(kwarg_name: str, **kwargs):
    print(kwarg_name)
    print(kwargs)


magic_params("my_parameter", my_parameter=1) # GOOD

magic_params("my_parameter", something_else=1) # BAD
```

In the above example, I would like the only valid keyword arguments to be derived from the first argument "my_parameter".

I'm fairly new to Python type-hinting and have tried playing around with ParamSpec and generics, but can't figure this one out.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @InSync This is a very boiled down version of a problem I am facing with a framework I am building. I likely can solve the problem more cleanly by rearchitecting, but at this point I was curious if it's even possible within python's type system.

Comment: You can't do this in Python's standard typing system. However, if you're using mypy, it's possible to write a [mypy plugin](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html) for something like this. I wouldn't use a plugin to do this if it's public-facing API though, you'd best to re-architect this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go here, depending on your exact use case. I can't be typed in exactly the way you describe, but there are some ways you can get quite close:

### A note about the function signature

In some way, it's worth point out that really there is redundant information in the function signature. Assuming there is only one key in the signature you're interested in, another way to write it would be:

```py
magic_params("my_parameter", **{"my_parameter":1})
```

So really the string "my parameter" is pretty redundent here. You could just as easily write:

```py
magic_params(my_parameter=1)
```

...and extract the name from the keyword args.

### `TypedDict` and `Unpack`

This syntax allows you specify the allowed keys in kwargs, but it won't let you derive this from a string:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Unpack

class Parameters(TypedDict):
    my_parameter: int

def magic_params(kwarg_name: str, **kwargs: Unpack[Parameters]):
    print(kwarg_name)
    print(kwargs)

magic_params("my_parameter", my_parameter=1) # GOOD

magic_params("my_parameter", something_else=1) # BAD
```

However, it should be noted this does not derive from the string provided.

### I really need to match the string type!

If you really need to provide both arguments separately, there is a way you can verify the string matches that provided in the kwargs - sadly this is not supported for unpack, so you have to use it as a regular dict:

```py
from typing import LiteralString, TypeVar

X = TypeVar("X", bound=LiteralString)

def magic_params(kwarg_name: X, kwargs: dict[X, int]):
    print(kwarg_name)
    print(kwargs)

magic_params("my_parameter", {"my_parameter":1}) # GOOD

magic_params("my_parameter", {"something_else":1}) # BAD
```

Hope this is useful!

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there is no built in approach for this. However, this seems to be a text-matching based problem. A bit of a hot take, but I do love regex for anything of that sort. You could use the input string(s) as your regex in the form of:

`paramReg = re.compile(r"(?i)<first argument string goes here>")` (added the ?i for ignore-case, entirely arbitrary)

Run a check against the input args as:
`bool(paramReg.search(<arg/variable names go here>))`

And use the True/False output to see if the same arg is being passed as the first string. However, that would imply knowing the *name* of a variable, which from what I've seen, is generally not an indicator of a good solution. Regardless, I was able to find another answer on SO that's asking how to get that information - most replies also echo the proposition that relying on variable names is not so good - but it could be helpful if you choose to continue on that path:

[How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python)

Best of luck!

Comment: This question is about type hinting, and what business does a regex have here?

Comment: OP: 'In the above example, I would like the only valid keyword arguments to be derived from the first argument "my_parameter"'. Yes OP mentioned type hinting, but had also asked for a way to validate that the kwarg being passed has the same identifier as the string being passed as the first argument. String evaluation is quite straightforward with regex @InSync

Comment: I'm afraid not every string operation needs regex. `len(kwargs) == 1 and kwarg_name in kwargs` is good enough.

Comment: @InSync Yes, anyone could tell you it does not need regex explicitly, but OP's comment that "This is a very boiled down version of a problem I am facing with a framework I am building" implies there could be other conditions that might apply. Regex is very lightweight and adds many headache mitigating options that direct string comparisons might not provide. Either is fine, but "good enough" is not conducive for "I'm building a framework". Many people are scared of regex, but it sure is graceful once you get familiar -- why be opposed to a more generalized option when it's just as easy?

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm scared of it; you shouldn't make assumptions, especially assumptions about requirements not explicitly stated in the question.