# How to retrieve a variable's name in python at runtime?

Tags: python

Is there a way to know, during run-time, a variable's name (from the code)?
Or do variable's names forgotten during compilation (byte-code or not)?

e.g.:

```
>>>  vari = 15
>>>  print vari.~~name~~()
'vari'
```

**Note**: I'm talking about plain data-type variables (`int`, `str`, `list` etc.)

Comment: Don't you have to type the variable name to get the name of it?

Comment: Yeah, well, it's been 3 years ago, and i don't remember why this question made sense. But woa! it's extremely popular, so there's something about it.

Comment: Here is a usage example: variables foo,bar,baz are there, I want to get a dictionary exactly as {'foo':foo,'bar':bar,'baz':baz}. Surely I can type out as what I just did, but not very succinct. `locals()`, in my opinion, pass too much information, not perfect. What I expect is a function like `magic_func([foo,bar,baz])` which returns the dictionary I want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I print original variable's name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/can-i-print-original-variables-name-in-python)

Comment: Interesting trick added in Python 3.8, that answered my usage need related to your question:
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here a basic (maybe weird) function that shows the name of its argument...
the idea is to analyze code and search for the calls to the function (added in the **init** method it could help to find the instance name, although with a more complex code analysis)

```
def display(var):
    import inspect, re
    callingframe = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    cntext = "".join(inspect.getframeinfo(callingframe, 5)[3]) #gets 5 lines
    m = re.search("display\s+\(\s+(\w+)\s+\)", cntext, re.MULTILINE)
    print m.group(1), type(var), var
```

please note:
getting multiple lines from the calling code helps in case the call was split as in the below example:

```
display(
        my_var
       )
```

but will produce unexpected result on this:

```
display(first_var)
display(second_var)
```

If you don't have control on the format of your project you can still improve the code to detect and manage different situations...

Overall I guess a static code analysis could produce a more reliable result, but I'm too lazy to check it now

Answer (score 35):

Variable names don't get forgotten, you can access variables (and look which variables you have) by introspection, e.g.

```
>>> i = 1
>>> locals()["i"]
1
```

However, because there are no pointers in Python, there's no way to reference a variable without actually writing its name. So if you wanted to print a variable name and its value, you could go via `locals()` or a similar function. (`[i]` becomes `[1]` and there's no way to retrieve the information that the `1` actually came from `i`.)

Comment: this solves my case.  then i make reverse lookup on their values, and find their names.  thanks.

Comment: The hard part about this is that if you only have `i' then it is impossible to find it's name in `locals()`. Consider 'i=1; j=1;'. After this 'locals()["i"] is locals()["j"]'. If all that you have is `i' then looping through locals() will result in finding either `i' or `j' as the name.

Comment: D. probably intended to say "If all that you have is `1` [...]"

Answer (score 12):

Variable names persist in the compiled code (that's how e.g. the `dir` built-in can work), but the mapping that's there goes from name to value, not vice versa. So if there are several variables all worth, for example, `23`, there's no way to tell them from each other base only on the value `23` .

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function I use to print the value of variables, it works for local as well as globals:

```
import sys
def print_var(var_name):
    calling_frame = sys._getframe().f_back
    var_val = calling_frame.f_locals.get(var_name, calling_frame.f_globals.get(var_name, None))
    print (var_name+':', str(var_val))
```

So the following code:

```
global_var = 123
def some_func():
    local_var = 456
    print_var("global_var")
    print_var("local_var")
    print_var("some_func")

some_func()
```

produces:

```
global_var: 123
local_var: 456
some_func: <function some_func at 0x10065b488>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. However, now I'm curious if this can be expanded to work for any expression given the context of when `print_var` is called. One use case would be to print both the name and value of a field of an object (e.g., `print_var('myobject.x')`)

Comment: That wasn't too hard actually: https://gist.github.com/anishpatel/e32f9cdc1df55692f418

Answer (score 3):

This will work for simple data types (str, int, float, list etc.)

```
def my_print(var_str) :
    print var_str+':', globals()[var_str]
```

Comment: It just needs to be noted, that if you have, say `ix = 200`, then you call this function with `my_print("ix")`.

Answer (score 3):

Nice easy solution using f-string formatting, which is native to Python 3.6 and later:

```
vari = 15
vari_name = f"{vari=}".split("=")[0]
print(vari_name)
```

Produces:

```
vari
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, it's just not pretty.

```
import inspect, sys


def addVarToDict(d, variable):
    lineNumber = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
    with open(sys.argv[0]) as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\n")

    line = lines[lineNumber-1]

    varName = line.split("addVarToDict")[1].split("(")[1].split(",")[1].split(")")[0].strip()
    d[varName] = variable


d = {}

a=1

print d # {}
addVarToDict(d,a)
print d # {'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following link from the post above with no success:
Googling returned this one.

http://pythonic.pocoo.org/2009/5/30/finding-objects-names

Comment: Except now that I've upvoted this one, it's not necessarily "the post above": we're talking about @piquadrat's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just yesterday I saw a blog post with working code that does just this. Here's the link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20090624235438/http://pyside.blogspot.com/2009/05/finding-objects-names.html

Comment: "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist."

Comment: @StuartWoodward: archive.org has a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20090624235438/http://pyside.blogspot.com/2009/05/finding-objects-names.html

Comment: It'll also only work in it's current form if it's used in the `main` python file, if it's imported it'll open the wrong file, so it'd need to be adapted.