# how to save/read class wholly in Python

Tags: python, class, autosave

```
som = SOM_CLASS() # includes many big difficult data structures
som.hard_work()
som.save_to_disk(filename)
#then later or another program
som = SOM_CLASS()
som.read_from_file(filename)
som.do_anythink_else()
```

or

```
som = SOM_CLASS()
save(som)
#...
load(som)
som.work()
```

what is easiest way to do this?

Comment: Any other requirement? Speed/size/security/portability? http://docs.python.org/library/json.html could be an option.

Comment: requirement = easy and fast to do this an do another work)

Comment: You should change this to "how to save/read object wholly in Python"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can (de)serialize with [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). It is backward-compatible, i.e. it will support all old protocols in future versions.

```
import pickle

som = SOM_CLASS()
fileObject = <any file-like object>
pickle.dump(som, fileObject)
#...
som = pickle.load(fileObject)
som.work()
```

But mind that if you transfer pickled objects to another computer, make sure the connection cannot be tampered with as [pickle might be unsecure](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure) (this is an article that every pickle user should know).

Another alternative is the older module [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html).

Comment: Nadia... Answering even when offline :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/97828/nadia-alramli

Answer (score 14):

I use this code:

```
import cPickle
import traceback

class someClass():
    def __init__(self):
        #set name from variable name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690400/getting-an-instance-name-inside-class-init
        (filename,line_number,function_name,text)=traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
        def_name = text[:text.find('=')].strip()
        self.name = def_name

        try:
            self.load()
        except:
            ##############
            #to demonstrate
            self.someAttribute = 'bla'
            self.someAttribute2 = ['more']
            ##############

            self.save()

    def save(self):
        """save class as self.name.txt"""
        file = open(self.name+'.txt','w')
        file.write(cPickle.dumps(self.__dict__))
        file.close()

    def load(self):
        """try load self.name.txt"""
        file = open(self.name+'.txt','r')
        dataPickle = file.read()
        file.close()

        self.__dict__ = cPickle.loads(dataPickle)
```

This code saves and loads the class from its actual class instance name. Code is from my blog http://www.schurpf.com/python-save-a-class/.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Brilliant, I wish I had thought of this myself! :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Python's [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pickle` in this way:

```
import pickle
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade # 0 - 100
    def get_grade(self):
        print (self.grade)
s1 = Student("Tim", 19, 95)

#save it
with open(f'test.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(s1, file) 

#load it
with open(f'test.pickle', 'rb') as file2:
    s1_new = pickle.load(file2)

#check it
s1_new.get_grade()
# it prints 95
```