# Converting an object in string type into Python object

Tags: python, oop

I have a tree structure stored in a text file. I want to read the file into Python and convert it into a [Node](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zss/1.1.4) object.

The standard way to build the tree is as follows:

```
from zss import Node

A = (
    Node("+") 
        .addkid(Node("+") 
            .addkid(Node("2")) 
            .addkid(Node("4")))
        .addkid(Node("*") 
            .addkid(Node("3")) 
            .addkid(Node("5"))) 
    )
```

Now I have the structure stored in a text file. e.g. A.txt

```
Node("+")
        .addkid(Node("+")
            .addkid(Node("2"))
            .addkid(Node("4")))
        .addkid(Node("*")
            .addkid(Node("3"))
            .addkid(Node("5")))
```

Is there a way to read A.txt into python as an object of class Node? I tried converting the file into a .py file and reading in however it was not successful?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html ?

Comment: Yeah, pickling it doesn't seem like such a bad idea. Storing the Python code in a text file seems kind of weird. I guess you could `eval` its contents (at your own risk).

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Thank you. I think pickle would do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save/read class wholly in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345151/how-to-save-read-class-wholly-in-python)