# How to get the variable name that instance the class?

Tags: python, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting an instance name inside class __init__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690400/getting-an-instance-name-inside-class-init)

I'm trying to solve this **little** problem:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "hello: %s" % i_dont_know

b = Test()
c = Test()
```

What I would like to get as a result:

```
hello: b
hello: c
```

**Just** the variable name.

I know that id(self) returns the reference code, it's possible to get the reference name ?

Comment: i think vars is what you are looking at ,, i'll post answer if my code works right

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538342/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: It's not possible, and it's the wrong question to begin with. Make it so you don't need it.

Comment: is it important to be at init ??

Comment: Since it's in `__init__`, you *might* be able to inspect the stack and pull out the line of code which called the constructor and then parse the variable name out of that (in the simple case that you have above) ... But I'm not even going to bother trying to write up that solution since you really shouldn't need to do this ...

Comment: EngHamoud: i tried the vars() no success
delnan, mgilson: i don't care if "it's the wrong question", i just want to know if it's possible, python give's to me a LOT of possibilities, then ...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  What if I do this:

```
Test()
```

or this:

```
someList[3] = Test()
```

or this:

```
someList.append(Test())
```

Comment: another one: `a = b = c = Test()`

Comment: Or `a = Test(); b = a; somelist[3] = b; somedict[a] = set([a]); someobject.nested.attribute = a; del a`?

Comment: i know that possibilities, i just think about inspect the globals, or locals to get the fast way to do what i want.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Besides the examples of BrenBarn, there is another insurmountable reason of why it's impossible. The constructor is completely executed *before* the assignment takes place.

Look at the bytecode:

```
>>> class Test(object): pass
... 
>>> def make_instances():
...     a = Test()
...     b = Test()
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(make_instances)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Test)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Test)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `CALL_FUNCTION` byte code is the one that executes `__init__`. `STORE_FAST` binds the object to the identifier. Python does not provide any way to interact with the binding, so there is no "special method" that could be used.

Comment: perfect answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to do something like

```
class Test:
    def __init__(name):
        self.name = name


    def __str__():
        return name


a = Test("a")

print a    
>>> a
```