# Joining same-key dictionaries into a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

How to create a pandas `DataFrame` out of two and more dictionaries having common keys? That is, to convert

```
d1 = {'a': 1}
d2 = {'a': 3}
...
```

into a dataframe with columns `['d1', 'd2', ...]`, rows indexed like `"a"` and values determined by the respective dictionaries?

Comment: this question have been asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel eh, I think only if you squint, unless you linked the wrong question by accident

Comment: @Ajean Dictionnaries could have been named d45, d34, .. etc with some random numbers. In that case the answer below does not work. The author in the link underlines this tricky point: "I would like to create a DataFrame in Pandas from this list, where the column names are given by the names of the actual dictionaries"

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Sorry, I should have been more clear - I really meant that that question is posed completely differently: the same true underlying question has been *answered* there (I think) but not really *asked* (until you read way down)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
d2 = {'a': 3, 'b':5}

df = pd.DataFrame([d1, d2]).T
df.columns = ['d{}'.format(i) for i, col in enumerate(df, 1)]
```

yields

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
   d1  d2
a   1   3
b   2   5
```