# How do I acces the name of a symbolic function in sage?

Tags: function, sage

Well, the question is pretty simple.
I have a symbolic function like

```
var('U I')
Z = U / I
```

and now I want to create a dictionary, where the name of the function (as a string), here Z, maps to the corresponding function. It's simple to do by hand

```
{ 'Z' : Z }
```

but I want it to be created automatically. Using `str(Z)` returns `U/I`, so this isn't helpful. I went through some documentation, but did not find any method that returns the name of a function as string.
So how do I do it? Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have not created a function at all.  You have created a *Python* variable, which refers to `U/I`, which is a "symbolic expression", and as such (for better or worse) is just itself.  See e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string) which I think is relevant.  This is also true for things like `Z(U/I)=U/I` and friends.

You could do

```
sage: def z(U,I):
....:     return U/I
....: 
sage: z
<function __main__.z>
sage: z.func_name
'z'
```

but that is a Python function and doesn't have the methods of a Sage function.

The following seems to work, but has a mysterious error I don't have time to track down right now, presumably because something in [the hash method](http://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/tree/src/sage/symbolic/function.pyx#n267) wants the code from a Python function, which isn't what we have here for `Z`.

```
sage: Z(U,I) = U/I
sage: z = function("z", nargs=2, eval_func=Z)
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError('sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object has no attribute '__code__',) in 'sage.symbolic.function.SymbolicFunction._hash_' ignored
sage: z(2,3)
2/3
sage: z.name
<function name>
sage: z.name()
'z'
```