# python print a variable as a string from a list

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to work out if this is posible. I want to print the varible name from a list. 
Here is my code

```
brisbane=[1,2,3,4]
sydney=[2,5,8,34,6,2]
perth=[2,4,3]

towns=[brisbane,sydney,perth]
```

I am doing some maths, then with these numbers I want to take the string 'brisbane' from the towns list and use it somewhat like this.

```
print 'the town witht the most rain was', towns[0], '.'
```

and print this as 'the town with the most rain was brisbane.'

Comment: You don't want to try to do that.  Use a dictionary.

Comment: If you want brisbane in your string then you have give it as a string. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/18425275/5039470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it would be easier for you to use a dictionary in this case , something like -

```
d = {'brisban':[1,2,3,4],
     'sydney':[2,5,8,34,6,2],
     'perth':[2,4,3]}
```

Then you can store the `keys` in the list towns , Example -

```
towns = list(d.keys())
```

And then when doing your maths , you can call each town's values as - `d[<town>]` , Example - `d['brisbane']` .

And after that you can get the corresponding town name from `towns` list.

Comment: Thanks
This is exactly what I was looking for. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to print a variable name at least not in the way you are presenting above.

Source:
[Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

In your case you could instead create a dictionary, like this:

```
towns = {}
towns['brisbane'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
towns['sydney'] = [2, 5, 8, 34, 6, 2]
towns['perth'] = [2, 4, 3]
print(towns)

{'sydney': [2, 5, 8, 34, 6, 2], 'perth': [2, 4, 3], 'brisbane': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do so. Check out the string formating documents here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

for your particular example, it would just be

`print ("the town with the most rain was {0}".format(towns[0]))`