# python - name of np array variable as string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code:

**I restated the problem formulation somewhat. Not sure if etiquette is to post a new question. If so, my bad**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0])
b = np.array([1,0])
c = np.array([2,0])

my_array_list = [a,b,c]
for my_array in my_array_list:
    np.save('string_that is representative of my_array',my_array)
```

where 'string that is representative of my array' equals to 'a', 'b', 'c' or similar.

There is likely a better way to solve this, I can just not come up with one right now.

What is the best way to do this, fast and efficiently?

Comment: No, because it might have more than one name (e.g., if you do `other_name = my_array`).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can suggest you that function:

```
import numpy as np

def namestr(obj, namespace):
    return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj]

my_numpy = np.zeros(2)
print(namestr(my_numpy, globals()))
```

With output:

```
['my_numpy']
```

Comment: thanks George, beautiful and simple solution. I actually changed the implementation to: return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj][0] and that is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Excellent solution by @GeorgePetrov above. Here just expanding it as tutorial:

**Given:** list of variables of any type e.g. ***[a,bb,c,d,e]***

**Output:** list of varibles' names in string form e.g. ***['a','bb', 'c', 'd', 'e']***

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,0])
bb = np.array([1,0,9,9])
c = ["cvghvgh", "kkk"]
d = 88
e = "bb"

variable_list = [a,bb,c,d,e]
str_var_list=[]

for i in range(len(variable_list)):
    str_var_list.append( [name for name in globals() if globals()[name] is variable_list[i]][0] )

print(str_var_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you initialize  it as a dictionary with key value pairs. this way you reference the key  (string) or the value (ndarray)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0])
b = np.array([1,0])
c = np.array([2,0])

my_array_list = {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
for key, value in my_array_list.items():
    np.save('{} is representative of {}'.format(key, value)
```