# numpy.ndarray object's name only converted to a string

Tags: python, string, numpy, type-conversion, computer-science

If I wish to get the name of a `numpy.ndarray` converted to a string (but not the content of the `numpy.ndarray`, just the name only), how do I do that?

I tried `str(npndarrayName)` and `npndarrayName.tostring()` but both are converting the content and not the name itself only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: In Python objects don't have names.  An object may be assigned to a variable - or many variables, or none.  So while is may, in some cases, be possible to look for the object in the global namespace, I question the practicality of this.  Why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: @hpaulj for a project. I want to plot something from a np.ndarray with its name as the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understood what you're asking, but you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980833/python-name-of-np-array-variable-as-string) because I think they had the same question as you.
I hope that it will solve your problem.