# Python Get Variable Name Inside Class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

In Python 3, if you have a class, like this:

```
LETTERS = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
class letter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.number = LETTERS.index(name)
        self.nextLetter = LETTERS[self.number+1]
        self.previousLetter = LETTERS[self.number-1]
```

and you create an instance of letter, myLetter, like this:

`myLetter = letter('c')`

In letter, how do I get the variable name? (myLetter in this case)

Comment: I'm not following. You created an instance of `letter` (you should capitalize your class names -> `class Letter`) called `myLetter` and now are asking how to get `myLetter` from `letter`?

Comment: Inside `letter`, I am trying to get `myLetter`.

Comment: inside `letter`, `myLetter` is named `self`.

Comment: @Daniel Oh. That's what the question was? I could not understand the question.

Comment: @Daniel Inside `letter`, when I print `self`, I get something like `<__main__.letter object at 0x00000181941AF588>`

Comment: Could you explain why you need this? Otherwise this seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't think of when I could **need** this, but I think it could be useful, for example, I could do `c = letter()` instead of `c = letter('c')`. Also if you passed an instance to something, (a function, or another class for example) it could be useful to know the instance's name. (Especially for testing)

Comment: An instance doesn't always have a variable name (or only one, for that matter). Consider `list_of_letters = [letter('a'), letter('b')]` or `a = b = letter('c')`. Which variable name would you expect in those cases? What you're asking for is generally not possible (though you *might* be able to get what you want by inspecting the stack), and shouldn't be used even if it was possible. Variable names are not data. If you want a mapping from a "name" string to an instance, use a dictionary.

Comment: This is nearly impossibel. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18425275/4273834

Comment: @Blckknght Those are some great points! When I asked this question I did not think of those cases.Thank you, everyone, for their interest.

Comment: This is the possible: https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname

Comment: @PanwenWang While that is an interesting project, in general this is a terrible idea and I only keep this question up to ward off anyone thinking of doing this just like I wanted to in 2016.

Comment: @nedla2004 Terrible idea I agree. But also sometimes useful and handy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of `myLetter` as a pointer to the class instance of `letter`. For example, if you have:

```
LETTERS = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
class letter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.number = LETTERS.index(name)
        self.nextLetter = LETTERS[self.number+1]
        self.previousLetter = LETTERS[self.number-1]

myLetter = letter('c')
myLetter2 = myLetter
```

Both myLetter and myLetter2 are aliases for the exact same myLetter instance. For example:

```
myLetter.number = 50
print(myLetter2.number)

>>> 50
```

So finding something to return the name of the `letter` instance within the `letter` class is ambiguous.