# Python: Convert Name of a Variable or Variable's Property into a String

Tags: python, string, pandas

i'm pretty sure there is a way to do this in Python, but i couldn't find a way. Thanks for the help.

- Customer.Name (Variable.Property)

Want to use the property's name directly in code, rather than hard-coded it.

```
colName = Customer.Name.*toString()*  
dataframe.drop(colName, 1)
```

Comment: Relevant resource:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple how to do this. just use the `str()` function.
For example:

```
vbl = True
print(str(bvl))
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Wondering how do i achieve the following:
`vbl = True`
`print(str(vbl))`
`vbl`
Which means instead of printing the content of a variable, can i just print the name of the variable (which is 'vbl' in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer.Name(str(Variable.Property))
```