# How can I print the name of variables in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function

I am trying to define the function which returns the name of variables.

```
>>> def function(x):
...     return(str(x))
... 
>>> a = 1
>>> function(a)
'1'
```

I want to define the following function. How can I define it?

```
>>> a = 1
>>> function(a)
a = 1
```

Comment: What shall the function print for `a = 1; b = a; function(a)`?

Comment: Can you please explain why exactly you need this to prevent the XY problem?

Comment: I'd prefer to tag this question as a duplicate of [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string), and in particular to point the OP to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425275/2749397): _"a name is a one-way reference to an object."_

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't possible as the input argument is evaluated before it feeds your function. In other words, the `'a'` variable name is lost, only the value `1` feeds your `function`.

If you feed the variable name as a string, you can use `globals`:

```
a = 1

def foo(x):
    return f'{x} = {globals()[x]}'

foo('a')  # 'a = 1'
```

Use of global variables is advisable only for specific purposes. If the variable name is important, you can use a dictionary instead:

```
d = {'a': 1}

def foo(myd, x):
    return f'{x} = {myd[x]}'

foo(d, 'a')  # 'a = 1'
```

In most situations, the dictionary will be sufficient.