# Saving file with the name of the array variable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am willing to save the file with the same name as the variable has. See teh following code:

```
training = np.arange(200)
np.savetxt(training.txt,training)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'txt'
```

When I use double quotes it will work as obvious:

```
np.savetxt("training.txt",training)
```

But in my program there are different variables and I want that when I call the file saving function the file name should automatically be taken as the variable name itself.
For example, if the variable is `question`, or `answer`, then when I say `save()`, the file name should automatically be `question.txt` or   `answer.txt`
Suggest me what I can do to achieve this.

Comment: You have this problem because your approach is incorrect: Collect your "different variables" into a Python dictionary (`dict`), then the variable names are dictionary keys, i.e. ordinary strings, and you can use them to construct filenames.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425523/4121573) might work, but I'd not recommend this approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: You might want to look into `numpy.savez` ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html ) to save many array objects into the same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good way this can work. A variable in Python is just a reference to the actual object. The name doesn't matter.

You need a way to store your variable with a given name, which is what associative tables are about, and that's a `dict` in Python.

This would resemble something like:

```
variables={}
variables["training"] = np.arange(200)
for key, val in variables.items():
    np.savetxt(key, value)
```

Comment: I have to disagree, you can make it work with `inspect` with all the dangers that come with it of course

Comment: @Adonis basically, you are hacking the variable system to get exactly the same, except that you won't be able to figure out which variable you actually want anyway. So no, `inspect` will not work properly either. How do you know which variables need to be saved?

Comment: In function if I pass the variable, then will the inspect work? I am looking at it.

Comment: You have a dictionary, so you will have to check which variables is the same as your variable, and the have the name. But that's fragile, and not a sound approach. The proper Pythonic way is to store the data with its name in a dictionary. After all, the local variables are a dictionary, you are just exposing and being explicit about what you do, which is the Python way.

Comment: @Adonis I liked your idea.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher May be I am not right the Pythonic way, but there has to have some way outside the way the world is doing. Adonis gave a good suggestion. I liked your answer too.

Comment: Personally, if one of my team members writes code using `inspect` for such a case, I'm refusing his code.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou Mathieu is right, and my idea is absolutely not a good one, just a possibility that I'd highly discourage, except to have some fun with Python's inner working

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and enlightening words.

Comment: Agreed, it's good sometimes to explore Python internals as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Working with identifier names in Python is cumbersome (and it is not intended to be a common practice). Why don't you try using a dictionary?

```
import np

my_dict = dict()

def save(name: str):
    np.savetext('{}.txt'.format(name), my_dict[name])

my_dict['training'] = np.arange(200)
save('training')
```

Answer (score 0):

A very hackish way is to get the variable name from local symbol table. If you know that you have only one array, you can simple get the first result..

```
>>> 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> training = np.arange(200)
>>> def getndarrayname(env):
...     return list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(env[x], np.ndarray), env.keys()))
... 
>>> getndarrayname(locals())
['training']
>>>
```

Comment: Not a right way, as it gives me a list of all the variables I am using. `['traning', 'data', 'data_slice', 'training']`, Now you could imagine.

Comment: Hehe, so this is not the answer for you. Maybe you could create one array in one function, so that only one array gets created in local scope...