# Python 3 getting variable name of boolean variables without changing scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note: this is an extension of the question posed by [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string/18425523?noredirect=1#comment97628845_18425523)
and particularly the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536047/5623899) by **@juan-Isaza**:

```py
import inspect

def variable_name(variable):
    '''
    Argument:
        variable: the variable to search for from outer-most frame inner-wards

    Returns:
        name (str): the string characters corresponding to the name of the
            variable
    '''
    for fi in reversed(inspect.stack()):
        names = [
            var_name
            for var_name, var_val in fi.frame.f_locals.items()
            if var_val is variable
        ]
        if len(names) > 0:
            return names[0]
```

The main issue is the line `if var_val is variable`. Why? well atomic values such as `True`, `False`, `None` all have the same id. So testing via `is` results in the first boolean variable matching.

When / why might this come up?

Suppose you are over-engineering a way to wrap a configurable command to launch via `subprocess`:

```py
def line_arg(arg):
    return '{} {}'.format(variable_name(arg), arg)

def short_arg(arg):
    return '-{}'.format(line_arg(arg)).split(' ')

def long_arg(arg):
    return '--{}'.format(line_arg(arg)).split(' ')

def flag_arg(flag, short=True):
    dashes = '-' if short else '--'
    return '{}{}'.format(dashes, variable_name(flag)) if flag else ''
```

then you might have:

```py
def some_bash_command(
    a_short_arg:str, 
    a_long_arg:str, 
    flag_1:bool=False
    flag_2:bool=True
):
    # ???
    command = [
        'some-bash-command',
        'some-sub-arg',
        *short_arg(a_short_arg),
        *long_arg(a_long_arg),
        flag_arg(flag1, short=True),
        flag_arg(flag2, short=True)
    ]
    return [part for part in command if part != '']
```

which you would then hope to have return (assuming `flag1=False`)

```py
[
    'some-bash-command',
    'some-sub-arg',
    '-a_short_arg',
    <a_short_arg_value>
    '--a_long_arg',
    <a_long_arg_value>
    '-flag2'
]

# then call subprocess.Popen(args = command, ...)
```

However, instead of `flag2` you will get the first boolean variable (for me `stop_on_error`).

A solution would be to replace the line `# ???` with:

```py
import uuid
def some_bash_command(...):
    if flag1: flag1 = uuid.uuid4() # <--- unique value
    if flag2: flag2 = uuid.uuid4() # <--- unique value
    ...
```

which will circumvent this issue.
Unfortunately, that code can not exist in `flag_arg`

```py
import uuid
def flag_arg(flag, short=True):
    if flag: flag = uuid.uuid4()   # <--- this is a no go
    dashes = '-' if short else '--'
    return '{}{}'.format(dashes, variable_name(flag)) if flag else ''
```

as then the `variable_name` function will return `flag` every time.

So the question is specifically how might one modify (if it is even possible) **@juan-isaza**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536047/5623899) to handle atomic values like `True` / `False` / `None` etc?

I understand that the example above is not the best example and in practice it may just be simpler to do list concatenation / string formatting than using the functions provided above. They are provides to be part of a MWE.

Comment: I have wrapped it up as a package: https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname, give it a try?