# How to reproduce variable names inside a print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I could use arrays and then this problem could be solved easily.

But I'm curious if there's another solution for my problem. 
I want to reproduce my variables (var1, var2, var3) inside the print function by concatenating "var" + x (1,2,3)

```
var1 = "one"
var2 = "two"
var3 = "three"

for x in range(1, 4):

    print ("var" + "%d" % (x))
```

desired output result:

```
one
two
three
```

What I get as a result is:

```
var1
var2
var3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `locals()` to get a dict mapping local variable names to their values, and then accessing it by the name as your code tries:

```py
var1 = "one"
var2 = "two"
var3 = "three"

for x in range(1, 4):

    print (locals()["var" + "%d" % (x)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vars()` to obtain a dictionary of the defined variables in the current module.

```
var1 = "one"
var2 = "two"
var3 = "three"

for x in range(1, 4):
    print (vars()["var" + "%d" % (x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()`

```
for x in range(1,4):
    print(eval("var"+str(x)))
```

However this can only be used for variable names that have a known pattern. Otherwise you need to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string/18425523)

Comment: Please don't suggest using eval to such a basic question. There are better, more pythonic ways... :)

Comment: Of course using `eval()` has its own problems. But I don't see what is wrong with using `eval()` in this specific problem. There are always more than one way to do something in python. How do you say using `eval()` is less "pythonic"?

Comment: Have a look at the two answers using `vars()` and `locals()`

Comment: Yes I saw them. They work just as fine as this solution. However `eval()` will be slower compared to them. You should not use `eval` such that it can be a security exploit (e.g. with `input`). I don't see such a problem here