# Python how to get the value with variable name?

Tags: python, variable-names

For example, we have the scores of three courses stored in `LIST`.

```
English, Maths, Physics = 89, 92, 93
LIST = [English, Maths, Physics]
for i in range(len(LIST)):
    print(LIST[i])
```

And I want the print style to be like `English, 89`, `Maths, 92`, `Physics, 93`. Here is a solution that defines another list `LIST_name`

```
English, Maths, Physics = 89, 92, 93
LIST = [English, Maths, Physics]
LIST_name = ['English', 'Maths', 'Physics']
for i in range(len(LIST)):
    print(LIST_name[i], LIST[i])
```

I am wondering if there is a built-in function or some other tricks that can help me directly convert `English` to `"English"`, without defining `LIST_name`? And if so, how? As Barmar commented below, what I am looking for is how to go from a value to the name of the variable it came from?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of a list. `{"English": English, "Maths": Maths, "Physics": Physics}`

Comment: There's no way to go from a value to the name of the variable it came from.

Comment: Or learn enough programming to create a class for the objects which contains their name, score, and other pertinent information for each instance.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for replying me, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The same value can be held in many variables.

Comment: What you're looking for is not possible in Python, or most programming languages.

Comment: Then [edit] your question to explain which actual problem you are hoping to solve and why a dictionary is unsuitable.

Comment: Maybe search for similar questions, and discover that basically every time a beginner asked for something like this, they ended up using a dictionary and understanding why this is a better solution.

Comment: @tripleee As Barmar said, and his description is much more precise. I want to achieve this goal that " go from a value to the name of the variable it came from".

Comment: The general feeling among experienced programmers is that if you need to do what you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong. Programming languages have data structures like dictionaries for a reason.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks again for these helpful comments and I really learned a lot from them.

Comment: Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string/18425523) out for why you cannot get variable names in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a method that takes variable keyword args as input and gives you `dict` with key value pair

```
 def marks(**m):
  return m

 d=marks(English=90,Maths=100,Physics=90)  #call method with keyword args
 print(d)
```

**Output :**

```
   {'English': 90, 'Maths': 100, 'Physics': 90}
```

You can also iterate `dict`

```
for k,v in d.items():
  print(k,v,sep=', ')
```

**Output**

```
English, 90
Maths, 100
Physics, 90
```

Comment: How will this work with his `LIST` variable?

Comment: This is the correct answer for a different question.

Comment: This is my knowledge sir, i'm still learning @Barmar

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Deadpool's answer, you can use:

```
>>> dict(English=82,Maths=92,Physics=93)
{'English': 82, 'Maths': 92, 'Physics': 93}
>>>
```

More matching your case would be:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)), dict(English=82,Maths=92,Physics=93).items())))
English, 82
Maths, 92
Physics, 93
>>>
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want to use a dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar Well otherwise i have to use that `globals` thingy

Answer (score 1):

Define a class that represents the object that you're working with and override the `__str__` (and optionally `__repr__`) function(s):

```
class Course(object):
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ', ' + str(self.score)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{0}.{1} object at {2}> {3}'.format(self.__class__.__module__,
                                            self.__class__.__name__,
                                            hex(id(self)), str(self))

English, Maths, Physics = list(map(lambda x:Course(*x), zip(['English','Math','Physics'],[89,92,93])))
```

Or, combine with the other suggestions using `dict`:

```
English,Maths,Physics = list(map(lambda x:Course(*x), dict(English=82,Maths=92,Physics=93).items()))
```

And then you can:

```
>>> LIST = [English, Maths, Physics]
>>> for i in LIST:
...     print(i)
...
English, 89
Math, 92
Physics, 93
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use a list of names like `['English','Math','Physics']`

Comment: @Barmar observed, and edited to account for that peculiar requirement.

Comment: he doesn't want to use a dictionary, either.

Comment: he doesn't want to do anything that requires him to enter the strings explicitly, he wants to get it automatically from the variables. Which isn't possible.

Comment: right. not possible, so, do something else that *is* possible. like any of these answers.