# Translate lists of objects into dict in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

**Inputs:**

```
x,y,z = 1,2,3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
some_dict = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

**Current code:**

```
x,y,z = 1,2,3
some_list = [x,y,z]

some_dict = {}

def convert(some_list):
    for i in some_list:
        some_dict[i.__name__ ] = i    
convert(some_list)
```

**Error:**

```
    some_dict[i.__name__ ]= i
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name_
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string/18425523

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: First, `[a, b, c, dssds]` is already a list, so `some_list = [a, b, c, dssds]` is sufficient. As you have found out, integer values do not have names. What you are trying to do cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ComplicatedPhenomenon and @Alex, thank you for pointing to the relevant post, here is the solution to my question:

```
import inspect

some_dict = {}
x,y,z = 1,2,3
some_list = [x,y,z]

def retrieve_name(var):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    return [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]

for i in some_list:
    some_dict[retrieve_name(i)[0]] = i

print(some_dict)
```