# How to treat a variable name created as a variable as a string in python

Tags: python, variables

I made a variable.

```
body_weight_1 = [34, 45, 45, 65, 56]
body_weight_2 = [33, 30, 40, 50, 90]
```

And, I expected to print 'body'.

```
str(body_weight_1)[:4]
```

But, the result is

```
[34
```

how to get word 'body' from 'body_weight_1' in this situation?

Comment: Its not that easy to get the name of the variable to a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string
In your case you are casting the list into a string which looks like `'[34, 45, 45, 65, 56]'` after that. So `str(body_weight_1)[:4]` give you than the first 3 chars of the string which is `'[34'`.

Comment: * give you than the first 4 chars of the string which is `'[34,'`. You forgot a comma in your result.

Answer (score 0):

How I already commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232679/how-to-treat-a-variable-name-created-as-a-variable-as-a-string-in-python/#comment102839170_58232679) is that its not that easy to get the string of a virable name. Instead you can create a dictionary:

```
data = { 
    'body_weight_1': [34, 45, 45, 65, 56], 
    'body_weight_2': [33, 30, 40, 50, 90] 
}

for key in data :
    # prints the first 4 chars of all keys
    print(key[:4])
```

Output:

```
>> body
>> body
```