# I want to create lists with their names including a variable but couldn't do so, could anyone suggest something

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
VC_I=[1,2,4,3]

for i in range(len(VC_I)):
  print(VC_i=[])
```

> TypeError: 'VC_i' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask here? It is not really clear with the title and the description. Going with the description the code is incorrect probably you want to try this `for i in range(len(VC_I)): print(VC_I[i])`

Comment: No, I want to create lists having names according to i in the loop

Comment: You have to format it in the output yourself: `print(f'vc[{i}]={vc[i]}')`. Even the new "debug format string" print(f'{vc[i]=}') won't work because it prints the symbolic expression without any interpolation so it's going to print `vc[i]=1` rather than `vc[0]=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use a dictionary for this purpose?

```
VC_I=[1,2,4,3]
x = {}
for i in range(len(VC_I)):
    x[VC_I[i]] = [value, you, want]
```

To access use:

```
print(x["key name"])
```

To do what you wanted,

```
x = dict(zip(VC_I, PAYLOAD_IN))
```

Comment: I can't bcuz I need to associate multiple values to that VC_i

Comment: So what you can do is simply, x[VC_I[i]] = ['your', 'values', 'here']

Comment: At the end I want something like this: VC_1=[1234ead,345eef,4567ea,123aaa], similarly VC_2=[] and so on...

Comment: I want them as lists for a reason

Comment: They stay as lists when assigned to a dictionary, you simply need to call the dictionary name and key (variable name) that you want to access. i've added an example at the bottom of my answer. You might want to go here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and read about what a dictionary is...

Comment: I want to do something like this:  I have got a list of VC_IN=[1,3,65,13,4,1,65,3] and a list of PAYLOAD_IN=[ 'a2','123','21','1a','ae','23','12','ef'] where PAYLOAD_IN[0] corresponds to VC_IN[0] and so on. Now I will find the different VC's from VC_IN that is 1,3,65,13,4 and want to create lists with the name VC_1, VC_3, VC_65 and so on and their respective payloads will be the data for the lists, now can you tell me how to exactly do this?

Comment: see my latest revision, it still uses dictionaries, which i still dont think you understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use special module to get variable name. See here: [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

BTW, to make your example correctly iterating just the values do the following:

```
VC_I=[1,2,4,3]
for i in range(len(VC_I)): print(VC_I[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need this, but you can use the `locals()` to do this. For example, given your code:

```py
VC_I=[1,2,4,3]
names_dict = dict(locals()) #Preserve a copy of all local variables
for key, val in names_dict.items():
    if val == VC_I:
        print('The variable name is:', key)
```

which will output, as you have guessed:

```py
The variable name is: VC_I
```

However, this will only work if you are working with local variables. It also wouldn't work for variables with the exact same values. Take note.

**edit**
You can even do this:

```py
for key, val in names_dict.items():
    if val == VC_I:
        print(key, ' = ', val)
```

which should give you:

```py
VC_I = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create list like VC_1, VC_2, ...
check this code

```
VC_I=[1,2,4,3,4,5,6,7,8]
PAYLOAD_IN=[ 'a2','123','21','1a','ae','23','12','ef'] 

for i in VC_I:
  name = 'VC_'+str(i)        
  print(name)                # here name variable is string
  name = list()
  print(name)                # here name variable is list
  print(type(name))          # checking data type of variable name
```

Answer for your specific question

```
for i, j in zip(VC_I, PAYLOAD_IN):
  name = 'VC_' + str(i)
  name = list()
  name.append(j)
  print(name)
```

Comment: I want to do something like this: I have got a list of VC_IN=[1,3,65,13,4,1,65,3] and a list of PAYLOAD_IN=[ 'a2','123','21','1a','ae','23','12','ef'] where PAYLOAD_IN[0] corresponds to VC_IN[0] and so on. Now I will find the different VC's from VC_IN that is 1,3,65,13,4 and want to create lists with the name VC_1, VC_3, VC_65 and so on and their respective payloads will be the data for the lists, now can you tell me how to exactly do this?

Comment: @Vinita hi upvote or mark this as answer if this solved your problem.