# Simple way to jsonify an simple array as key: value

Tags: python, flask

Is there a simple way in python/flask to jsonify an array of strings as a key/value pair?

So far I understood, that I can jsonify with following code:

```
fruits = ["apple", "pear", "melon"]
return jsonify(fruits)
```

which returns

```
["apple", "pear", "melon"]
```

Now, what is the simplest way to get this as a key/value like

```
{
    "fruits": ["apple", "pear", "melon"]
}
```

Comment: Are you asking what a dictionary is?

Comment: well. my question would be rather: Do I have to make a dictionary first then jsonify, or is there simple predefined function which makes this in a one-liner

Comment: You would have to make a dictionary first, then json.dumps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string) for an explanation as to why this isn't simple to implement.

Instead, try:

```
import json
obj_dict = {"fruits": ["apple", "pear", "melon"]}
print(json.dumps(obj_dict))
```

Comment: this got me to the idea, which worked perfectly
    fruits = ["apple", "pear", "melon"]

    return jsonify({"fruits": fruits})

An one-liner, thnx

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
let fruits = ["apple", "pear", "melon"]
let fruitsObj = { fruits }
let json = JSON.stringify(fruitsObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple convertion

```js
fruits = ["apple", "pear", "melon"]

function newFruits (array){
  return {fruits: array}
}

console.log(newFruits(fruits))
```