# String representation of attribute in Python

Tags: python, attributes, dry, introspection

Is there a way to get the string representation of a single `NamedTuple` (or perhaps another type's) attribute?

The snippet below instantiates a `pandas.Series` indexing a value using a `str` key matching where the value came from.

If you later want to change the name of `attr_1` to `some_useful_attribute_name`, and want this reflected in the pandas series index, the code below requires two changes.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import NamedTuple

class MyTuple(NamedTuple):
    attr_1: int
    attr_2: float
        
mt = MyTuple(1, 1)
ser = pd.Series(data=[mt.attr_1], index=['attr_1'])
```

People often miss the second change when the series instantiation is far away from the class definition.

Refactoring tools such as Pycharm's help somewhat, as they can identify all the `attr_1` strings. However, if instead of `attr_1` the string is more common, such as `level` or whatever else, it becomes rather tedious to identify the correct strings to change.

Instead of the last line of code above I'd therefore like to do something like

```
ser = pd.Series(data=[mt.attr_1], index=[repr(mt.attr_1)])
```

except that of course `repr()` doesn't give me the name of the attribute, but rather the string representation of its contents.

I am also aware of the `NamedTuple._asdict()` method. However the use case here is one where only selected attributes go into the series rather than the entire dictionary.

**EDIT:**
Might something be achieved by combining Enum and NamedTuple in a clever way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18425225/9608759