# How to get the name of a value in an enum declaration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

In Python3.7.7, I would like to use the name of an Enum value in the declaration of another value of the same Enum.

My first try:

```
from enum import Enum
class test(Enum):
    value1 = "a"
    value2 = value1.name + "b"
```

This returns an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`. I tried using `self.value1` and `test.value1` instead and both return a `NameError`.

I could just use `value2 = "value1b"` but I fear that it would give me weird errors down the line if I ever change the name of `value1` and forget some places instead of an immediate error because of an undefined variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During Enum class creation the values are just values -- they are not converted to Enum members until the end of the class definition.

There is nothing currently in the class definition machinery to support your use-case; however, you can use the functional syntax to generate your Enum:

```
# some code to calculate your names and values (not shown)
# that results in
members = (('value1', 'a'),('value2', 'value1a'))
test = Enum('test', members)
```

Which results in:

```
>>> list(test)
[<test.value1: 'a'>, <test.value2: 'value1a'>]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve is not simple, because you can only directly reference from a variable to the value, not vice versa.

I think the easiest solution is using **Python3.8+** and using the [debugging feature of f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) *(emphasis mine)*:

> To **display both the expression text and its value** after evaluation, (useful in debugging), an equal sign '=' may be added after the expression.

So the code would turn into:

```
from enum import Enum

class test(Enum):
    value1 = "a"
    value2 = f"{value1=}".split("=")[0] + "b"
```

Other solutions, also working with Python3.7- can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string). But they are more complicated to implement.

Comment: I saw the post you link, I hoped that there was some kind of magic available for enums. Too bad that there isn't!