# How to update the list so that each value in the list is converted to string?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I initialized characters in a list without using quotes. I want to update every value in the list so that each element in the list is converted to string so that i can use the list.

```
list1=[1,2,3,A,B]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i]=str(list1[i])
print(list1)
```

I tried to update every element in the list by converting it to a string but even then i got the error.

**Error Message:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/any.py", line 1, in 
list1 = [1,2,3,A,B]
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: you will have to define A and B first.

Comment: You need to provide error message, too.

Comment: @ktalik do u mean I have to use exception handling

Comment: @Anudeep Kosuri please post the text of your error message.

Comment: `list1=[1,2,3,A,B]` what is the type of `A` and `B` here?

Comment: @ktalik I updated my question with an error message . Thanks for letting me know about that.

Comment: you can't use string without quotes. your code always throws an error as of my knowledge none of the programming languages supports this kind of task

Comment: @deadshot that's why I want to reassign the same list by converting all the values of list to string .

Comment: your code not even runs how do you convert? it's not possible

Comment: So `A` and `B` values aren't even defined. I think your problem is caused by fundamental lack of understanding how Python works. You cannot use a variable if it's not defined / declared yet. Please read more about that and good luck learning Python!

Comment: @Ktalik  I got a doubt whether this is possible or not if its possible then how can we do it. It doesn't mean I didn't have fundamental knowledge. Programming means making impossible things possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all variables are unique, you can solve it with `locals()` method:

```
A = 4
B = 5
list1 = [1,2,3,A,B]

list2 = [None] * len(list1)

items = list(locals().items())

for i in range(len(list1)):
    for k,v in items:
        if v == list1[i]:
            list2[i] = k
            break
    if list2[i] is None:
        list2[i] = str(list1[i])
    
print(list2)
```

If not, please see this question for more information: [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18425225/1473454)

Comment: Thank you bro. Though it didn't worked for all characters it answered my question correctly. I am trying it for so many days whether it is possible or not . Really nice effort @ktalik

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `A` and `B` are already defined in your code, You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
list1 = [1,2,3,A,B]
strlist = [str(n) for n in  list1]
```

Comment: What error? You need to be specific. Also as said in comments `A` and `B` needs to be defined before use.

Comment: Yes, I read your comment don't get me wrong  but how to define them?

Comment: By assigning value to variable

Comment: if you define `A` and `B` you will never get this output `[1,2,3,'A','B']` it will convert the values of `A` and `B` to string not variable names

Comment: Okk but I want to covert A to 'A'. I have tried a lot doing it in all possible ways.But I got some error while doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize characters in a list without using quotes.
But you can use like..

```
list1 = [1,2,3,'A','B']

str_list = [str(n) for n in  list1]

print(str_list)
```