# How to get string name of defined variable in python?

Tags: python, text-extraction, variable-names

We know that in python you can get the name of a defined function: eg.

```
def f(x):
    return x

print(f"we've just defined function {f.__name__}")
```

Let's say i create a variable:

```
x = 4
```

Now at some point i would like to do:

```
print(f"you have defined a variable named {x.__name__}")
```

But the syntax above gives an error because `x` doesn't have such an attribute.

Is there a way to get the variable's name from its value, just as we can do with the value of a defined function ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: `a=b=c=1`. Which name should be returned for value 1? Objects can have multiple names.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your example can be simplified to `print("you have defined a variable named x")` since you already know the variable name `x`, but I doubt that this is what you want.

Comment: add complete code here so else can understand what you doing

Comment: Your code can monitor the contents of `globals()` for the appearance of entries it does not already know about.

Answer (score 0):

In the interpreter, you can simply call dir() and it will output all of the variables currently initialized in the interpreter. You can also show them using a script by writing

```
print(dir())
```

An example of this output is shown below:

```
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'math', 'numpy', 'plt', 'polar', 'r', 'theta', 'time', 'x', 'y']
```

Note that each of these variables are listed in alphabetical order, and can be iterated through as a list object.