# Get name of every variable in a list and convert to string

Tags: python

Is there a simple way of getting the name(not contents) of every list item and converting it to string?

```
text0= " zero zero zero zero..."
text1= " one one one.... "
text2= " two two two...."
text3= " three three...."


text_grouped=[text0, text1, text2, text3]

for i in text_grouped:
    print(i)
```

the above prints the contents of variables but not the actual names.

I would like the result to be:  text0, text1, text2, text3

Comment: not unless you have a `namedtuple` or a `dictionary` to map names with the values.

Comment: Why are you storing it this way anyway? Seems like you'd be better off with a dictionary. Why do you need the variable names? This is highly suggestive you need a dict, rather than some hacky way to retrieve "variable names".

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: If you have a specific pattern in the name of the list then you can find them from `dir()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `varname` library (its not part of the standard python library, so you have to install it). Sample code:

```
from varname import nameof

some_var1 = "somevar1"
some_var2 = "somevar2"
lst = [somevar1, somevar2]
print(nameof(lst[0]), nameof(lst[1]))
```