# Python: How to use an object name to call the object itself and also as a string

Tags: python, string, function, object

I need a little help with the following. If the answer is already out there and I didn't found it feel free to direct me to it :)

Explanation: I need to use the name of an object to call the object itself (easy) but also that very name as a string itself. So if I use the object 'some_object' inside a function I want to use that object and also to print the objects name -  in this case 'some_object'.

```
some_object = 'xyz'


def some_function(object_name):
    print()  # should print the objects name
    print(object_name)


some_function(some_object)  # in this case it should print 'some_object'

# desired output: 
# some_object
# xyz
```

I really hope this is possible. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: Objects don't have names. You may find things that look sort of like they do what you're looking for, but they don't - they got upvoted by people who either didn't test them thoroughly or didn't test them at all.

Comment: Relying on the names that point to objects for anything is a very bad idea that cannot lead to anything good

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica maybe I didn't expressed myself clear enough. Let me rephrase it. How can I print the argument inside the function as a string (meaning written characters themselves)

Comment: Your function is only given an object. It sees `'xyz'` and that's it. It has no idea that the object was assigned to a variable previously, nor what name the variable had. Unless you give it a different object containing name information, you cannot really do what you are asking for.

Comment: @FricativeMelon thank you that helps me. Would the other way around be possible. Provide the function with the string 'some_object' and then let it find the object that is assigned to that variable?

Comment: @peter That's what `dict`s are for: mapping a string (or any other hashable value) to another value. You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html as a refresher for how Python names work.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the link. I will definitely check it out. However I want to avoid dicts at all cost.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: @peter `globals()['some_object']` would give `'xyz'`. So your function can take the name of a global variable as a string, and get the value using that. Note that `globals()` is actually just a dictionary, containing all variables in global scope.

Comment: @FricativeMelon Yaaaay. This is exactly what I was looking for!!! I assume using `globals()['some_object']` is identical to `some_object` in terms of what happens computationally in the background. I am more than happy to mark this as a solution if you provide this as an answer.

Comment: @chepner I have a lot of objects and wrapping all of them inside a dict would be too inefficient.

Comment: A big thanks to everyone who spent time to help me!

Comment: @FricativeMelon: That only works in the same module, and only for globals. Using that approach actively hinders maintainability of your code by forcing you into practices like overly-large "god" files and global variable abuse.

Answer (score 1):

The only method to me would be to use dictionaries.
You refer the name of your key: then print this key with its value, and you should be good.
I checked other info about this online, but it talks about classes and doing too compex stuff to do a simple thing like this.

When you create a variable and assign to this variable a value, the function dosen't care about the fact that the given value comes from a variable or not.
I may be wrong but had to try helping, good luck.

Comment: Using this method would be very impractical for me but your suggestion is very appreciated. Maybe you have some ideas regarding my second questions in the comments.

Comment: @peter print some_function.func_globals.keys()[some_function.func_globals.values().index(param)]