# How to get name of a tuple inside of a tuple

Tags: python

Let's say I have:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5)
b = (2,4,5,6,7)
c = (a,b)
```

where a, b and c are tuples. How do I get the name of 'a' and 'b'?
I was trying with:

```
for x in c:
    print(type(x).__name__)
```

but it gives me tuple

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: There's a subtle distinction here. The tuple doesn't *have* a name; it may have one (or more) names that *refer* to it, but an object doesn't track those names.

Comment: What if you do: `z = a; c = (a, b)`? What do you expect the names inside `c` to be?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not names given to the tuples, it's rather the other way around: the tuples are assigned to these names. The tuples themselves are in no way connected to these names. Could you use a `dict` instead? E.g.: `c = {"a": a, "b": b}` and if you need only the values, just use `c.values()`.

Comment: Your loop would then be: `for k,v in c: print(k)` with k the key (name) and v the value (tuple in this case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Answer (score -2):

The `python-varname` package allows you to inspect variable names in general. Maybe that will help you. You can get it with `pip install varname`. Its GitHub is [here](https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname) and the README there provides usage examples.

edit: actually, for your use case, the comment given by @chepner is spot-on. I'll leave this answer up in case the package is of use to someone trying to get a variable name for a different case, since it would work on for example `a` and `b` themselves. But @chepner explains exactly why getting 'a' and 'b' out of 'c' is not going to be possible.

Comment: Aside from just being a terrible idea, `python-varname` doesn't actually do what you think it does. It's based on AST inspection, so you can't do something like `for thing in stuff: print(nameof(thing))` and get the "original" names of the things in the list. You'll get `'thing'` every time.