# How can I change dataframe names in a list to string with python?

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

How can I change data frame names in a list into the string with python?

```
list = [a,b,c,d]
# each element in the list is a dataframe
# I wanna change this list into
["a","b","c","d"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
def get_df_name(df):
    return [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
l = [a,b,c]

l = list(map(get_df_name,l))
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_