# How to return the list name in for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

list_all = [list1,list2]
```

My question is in a for loop how to get the list1 and list2 as a name of the list:

```
for i in list_all:
    print(list1.name,list2.name)
```

Output should like:

```
"list1",'list2'
```

Comment: Your `list_all` is *exactly equivalent* to `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` - there is absolutely no way to tell that the sub-lists came from individual variables, rather than being written directly in the assignment.

Comment: Related: [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the lists dictionaries you can provide a name

```
list1 = { "name": list1, "list": [1,2,3]}
list2 = { "name": list2, "list": [4,5,6]}

list_all = [list1,list2]

for i in list_all:
    print(list_all[i].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated and inefficient but it works:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list_all = [list1,list2]
i = k = v = None 
# we need this line to avoid "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" so locals() will recognize them
loc = locals().items()

for i in list_all:
 for k,v in loc:
  if v is i and k != 'i':
    # if id(v) equal to id(i)
    print(k)
```

and the output will be:

```
list1
list2
```