# dictionaries with different names and how to print the name

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Pets: Make several dictionaries, where the name of each dictionary is the
name of a pet. In each dictionary, include the kind of animal and the owner’s
name. Store these dictionaries in a list called pets. Next, loop through your list
and as you do print everything you know about each pet.

Hi i have this question.  I have done the solution but i would like to print the dictionaries name without writing print for each

solution:

```
jumbo = {"kind":"cat",
         "owner":"Rahma",
}
 


snoopy = {"kind":"dog",
          "owner":"fahad",
}


shilla = {"kind":"bird",
          "owner":"farooq",
}


pets = [jumbo,snoopy,shilla] # created list 

#loop through your list and as you do print everything you know about each pet

for pet in pets :
    print ( "jumbo" + " is "+ pet["kind"] + " the owner is " + pet["owner"].title() + "." ) )
```

The problem is i am  trying to print the names in each loop using the list pets that was created

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Include the name of the pet in the pet's dictionary, as an extra field: `jumbo = { 'name': 'jumbo', "kind":"cat", "owner":"Rahma" }`

Comment: I got the question from a book so i can't rephrase it #Petr L

Comment: jumbo = { 'name': 'jumbo', "kind":"cat", "owner":"Rahma" } this going to work perfectly . but is there another way of doing it ? I am learning that's why i am asking -stef

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this two solutions:

First - Zip with lists of pets name:

```
names = ["jumbo", "snoopy", "shilla"]

# loop through your list and as you do print everything you know about each pet

for name, pet in zip(names, pets):
    print(name + " is " + pet["kind"] + " the owner is " + pet["owner"].title() + ".")
```

Second - add the name to the dictionary:

```
jumbo = {"name": "jumbo", "kind": "cat",
         "owner": "Rahma",
         }

snoopy = {"name": "snoopy", "kind": "dog",
          "owner": "fahad",
          }

shilla = {"name": "shilla", "kind": "bird",
          "owner": "farooq",
          }
for pet in pets:
    print(pet["name"] + " is " + pet["kind"] + " the owner is " + pet["owner"].title() + ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eval()` like below(see [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)):

```
jumbo = {"kind":"cat",
         "owner":"Rahma",
}

snoopy = {"kind":"dog",
          "owner":"fahad",
}

shilla = {"kind":"bird",
          "owner":"farooq",
}

pets = ['jumbo','snoopy','shilla'] # created list 

for pet in pets :
    print ( (pet) + " is "+ str(eval(pet)["kind"]) + " the owner is " + str(eval(pet)["owner"]) + "." )
```

output:

```
jumbo is cat the owner is Rahma.
snoopy is dog the owner is fahad.
shilla is bird the owner is farooq.
```

Comment: I would not recommend this method in any serious program. The name of the variable and the name of the pet should not be dependent on each other. This is how we end up with spaghetti code.

Comment: @lachi007, welcome, please don't forget `accept` answer and `upvote`

Comment: Hi thank you for the reminder . I will do that .