# How to make argument return his own name?

Tags: python, list, kivy

My code

```
for i in list_tasks:
    globals()['icon1%s' % i].bind(on_press=lambda x: **print(#here I want to print his name)**
```

for example `globals()['icon1%s' % i]` is "icon1clock" I want it to print his own name (icon1clock) on press.

Comment: Can you give us an hint of what kind of object is icon1clock?

Comment: icon1clock is a button, I need him to get the name of himself

Comment: First of all, don't use individual variables like `icon1clock`. Use a *dict* with keys, e.g., `icons['clock'] = ...`.

Comment: The name is `'icon1%s' % i`.  Print that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the nature of your button object. But if it's an instance of class you could print its name like shown: `[globals()['icon1%s' % i].bind(on_press=lambda x: print(x.__name__)) for i in list_tasks] `

Comment: @John How? It’s not as simple as it looks.

Comment: If `print('icon1%s' % i)` doesn't work, please explain why.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: @JohnGordon Because `i` is a free variable in the body of the lambda expression, not the value read from `list_tasks`. By the time the callback is called, `i` has probably gotten a new value.

Comment: @John Because by the time the callback triggers, `i`’s value has changed.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is defining a lambda expression that wraps another *value*, rather than a name. I wouldn't bother trying. Write a function that *creates* the callback for you; the callback can be a *closure* over a variable.

```
def make_callback(name):
    def _(x):
        print(name)
    return _


# *Not* icon1clock = ...
icons = {
    'clock': ..., 
}

for i in list_tasks:
    icons[i].bind(on_press=make_callback(i))
```