# Printing the name of a variable instead of the variable itself in a for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, namespaces

I have several data frames: df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, etc.

I am trying to loop through them, perform an operation and output the *name* of the dataframe rather than the dataframe itself.

```
for k in [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]:
    k.RandomField.value_counts() #or whatever operations
    print(k) #this is where I want it to show "df_1", "df_2", etc instead of printing the variable which, in this case, would be the data frame
```

I know I can create a dictionary but that requires manually generating one. Appreciate your help.

[I am working in Jupyter notebooks and running Python 3.8.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: But you have to manually generate the list anyway, so why is it any different? If you can populate the list, you can populate the dict

Comment: This is a good example why one should never use variables when working with many objects, but a **container**. How did you generate the variables? Go back from there and store the values in a list/dictionary.