# Obtaining a string version of the variable name in Python

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```py
x,y = 0,1
for i in [x,y]:
   print(i) # will print 0,1
```

Suppose I wanted instead to print:

```
x=0
y=1
```

I realise `f-strings` can be used to print the intermediate variable name:

```py
for i in [x,y]:
    print(f"{i=}") # will print i=0, i=1
```

However, I am interested in the actual variable name.

There are other workarounds: using `eval` or using `zip([x,y], ['x', 'y'])`, but I was wondering if an alternative approach exists.

Comment: You'd need to hardcode it. But given you're the one writing the code anyway, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: I suppose you could check `locals()`/`globals()` and try to figure out which name corresponds to the value you have, but that leaves room for error if multiple variables have the same value, and again, when you're the one writing the code there really isn't any point.

Comment: How about reference this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364138/10998724 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425523/10998724

Comment: @SEUNGFWANI thank you, these are what I was looking for, though it turns out the answer is not so simple!

Answer (score 0):

I think this achieves what you want to do -

```
for i in vars():
    print(f'{i}={vars()[i]}')
```

Comment: This works for showing all the variables, but doesn't work for iterating over a list with specific variables.